# KOMA classes and \LoadClass

Tags: koma-script, paper-size, documentclass-writing, package-options, class-options

I want to create a document class based on a KOMA-Script class. If `myclass.cls` contains the following

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2011/08/31]
\LoadClass[paper=a5]{scrartcl}
```

then compiling a document whose first line is `\documentclass{myclass}` generates the warning

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [paper=a5].
```

The same problem occurs with `scrbook` and `scrreprt`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're looking for the option `a5paper` and not `paper=a5`.

Comment: no, `paper=a5` is correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option `paper` is actually not a class option, but an option of the `typearea` package which is implicitly used by all KOMA-Script classes. Hence, what you need is the following:

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2011/08/31]
\PassOptionsToPackage{paper=a5}{typearea}
\LoadClass{scrartcl}
```

The `paper` option isn't automatically passed to the `typearea` package by the KOMA-Script classes. On the other hand, this *is* the case for the old-style `a4paper`, `a5paper` etc. options. Thus, an alternative solution to your problem is:

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2011/08/31]
\LoadClass[a5paper]{scrartcl}
```

I don't recommend the latter solution, though, since old-style options are more and more deprecated by the KOMA-Script classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be something like this:

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2011/08/31]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[paper=a5]{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{...}
...
```

Comment: I've tested your solution. The warning is still there.