# Create a document class based on a KOMA-Script class: paper size problem

Tags: koma-script, documentclass-writing

I want to create a document class based on a KOMA-Script class. First I would like change paper size, which would be defined in cls file. I see that similar problem was questioned in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27109/koma-classes-and-loadclass?rq=1), but without clear solution. Has anyone of you an example of own document class based on a scrbook?

**wikibook.cls:**

```
\ProvidesClass{wikibook}[2013/06/30]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[paper=b4]{scrbook}
```

or alternative:

```
\ProvidesClass{wikibook}[2013/06/30]
\PassOptionsToPackage{b4paper}{typearea}
\LoadClass{scrbook}
```

**test.tex:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{wikibook}   
\usepackage{bookman} 
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\begin{document}    
   \chapter{First example} 
     \section{Section one}    
       \lipsum[2-8]   
   \chapter{Second example} 
     \section{Section two} 
\end{document}
```

Generated pdf size is persistently a4.

Comment: You can define your own option `paper` and pass the value to `typearea`.

Comment: Or, even better, `\PassOptionsToPackage{paper=b4}{typearea}
\LoadClass{scrbook}`

Comment: I try karlkoeller recomendations, but without any effects. Generated pdf size is persistently a4. :-(

Comment: Override `typeare` with `\RequirePackage[b4paper]{geometry}` after `\LoadClass{scrartcls}` and set the page parameters using `\geometry`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package `typearea` does support ISO paper sizes including the B series. But the package does not automatically tell the paper size to the output driver. Then the layout is calculated for the specified paper size, but the media size of the PDF file gets the default size of the output driver. Package `typearea` provides option `pagesize` for telling the paper size to the output driver, see "Table 2.6.: Output driver for option `pagesize=output driver`" of [KOMA-Script's documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf).

Example for the class file:

```
\ProvidesClass{wikibook}[2013/06/30]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\PassOptionsToPackage{paper=b5,pagesize=auto}{typearea}
\LoadClass{scrbook}
```

Comment: jafan wanted to use b4 paper. Using such a format you get a warning from `typearea` package. Do you know why?

Comment: @karlkoeller: Which warning?

Comment: Package typearea Warning: Bad type area settings!

Comment: @karlkoeller: I cannot reproduce it, because I do not get any warning (except for `Overfull \hbox` messages).

Comment: Is it somehow possible to take an option such as paper=a5 given to my own class, pass this option to typearea and all other options to the koma script class?

Comment: @Dan: `\DeclareOption{paper=a5}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{typearea}}`. Supporting any paper sizes is more difficult. Then a key value option parser would be needed, see package `kvoptions`.