# Conditionally add author to header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, documentclass-writing, scrartcl

I've a documentclass `myclass` that's based on KOMA-script's `scrartcl` class.

MWE: `myclass.cls`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

% The document class name
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121829
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\PassOptionsToPackage{headlines=3}{typearea}

% The document class to base this class on
\LoadClass{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% The page headers
\lohead{\csname @author\endcsname\\Foo\\Bar}
```

How do I conditionally insert `\csname @author\endcsname\\` in the beginning of `lohead` iff the argument to the command* `\author{}` is non-empty? The issue is that currently a newline is always inserted into the header.

---

* Unsure of the terminology here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like Koma-Script does, have a look at the definition of `\maketitle` in `scrartcl.cls` for examples.

```latex
\makeatletter
  \lohead{\ifx\@author\@empty\else\@author\\\fi Foo\\Bar}
\makeatother
```

If you are sure that `\@author` will not be changed after `\begin{document}`, you can also do the check just once.

```latex
\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \ifx\@author\empty
      \lohead{Foo\\Bar}%
    \else
      \lohead{\@author\\Foo\\Bar}%
    \fi
  }
\makeatother
```